# Difference between "afterwards" and "subsequently"

Tags: adverbs, synonyms

What is the difference between "afterwards" and "subsequently"?

Comment: Right now, it looks like this question could be answered by consulting a dictionary.  Perhaps you can update your question to specify exactly what problem you're having with these two words and why the dictionary entries don't resolve this problem.

Comment: one *syntactic* difference is that we usually place adverbial "subsequently" *before* the verb, but "afterwards" normally comes *after* the verb. So it's *We **subsequently discovered** that he was an impostor*, but *We **discovered afterwards** that he was an impostor*. But there are probably *lots* of differences, including semantics and idiomatic usages.

Comment: Do you mean differences in meaning or differences in syntax?

Comment: Of course, I mean dirrenece in meaning.

Comment: Americans tend to favor ***afterward*** where Brits favour ***afterwards***, but both versions mean the same and are used in the same way. In general, ***subsequently*** is more likely in "formal" contexts, but that's a very fine point of usage. As is the fact that until a century ago, ***afterward/s*** was *far* more common than ***subsequently***.

Comment: Consequently, they are both interchangeable, but "afterwards" is older.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think 'afterwards _verb_' is just a bit more formal and/or old-fashioned, and I wouldn't find it odd even in normal speech - _The acts of a person acting as a director are valid notwithstanding that it is afterwards discovered—. (a)that there was a defect in his appointment..._ Companies Act 2006 (UK Parliament) - _I could not picture a father treating a dying child as tyrannically and wickedly as I afterwards learned Heathcliff had treated him_ (I forget the author and title).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I was actually quite surprised to discover from NGrams that over the course of the past century, ***subsequently*** has overtaken ***afterward/s***. Plenty of people would say things like *We saw a movie and went to the pub afterward/s*, but I find it hard to imagine "normal" people in casual conversation using ***subsequently*** instead of ***afterward/s*** in a context like that.

Comment: "Subsequently" is completely absent from casual conversation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Heathcliff? Must be _Wuthering Heights_, surely!

Comment: @KateBunting - I was being facetious!

Comment: @cruthers - not from mine.